# Text in html table cell not visible!

Tags: html

I have the following html and the text for the input "fg" is not visible.

```
<td style="background-color: white;">
<input id="NormalDay1" class="tsm_textbox" type="text" value="fg" size="20" name="NormalDay1" style="background-color: white;"/>
</td>
```

I have checked for any color attributes in firebug but can't see any.

Any ideas why?

Malcolm

Comment: Can you show us the css rules for `#NormalDay1`, and `.tsm_textbox`?

Comment: it shows up fine for me when I test it. Have you checked the element in firebug to see if it's actually containing "fg"? (that way you can determine if it's a functional error or a display error)

Comment: `.tsm_textbox { font-size:7pt; text-align:center; border: none 0px; }`

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, when you refresh a page, input fields maintain their previous value, regardless of what the `value` attribute is in the HTML. Select the address bar and press enter, and it should revert to its default text.